# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) admin-ajax.php

Tags: ajax, tinymce

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) admin-ajax.php while insert image in to post, and when I
>   add custom html widget in to side bar this error will appear.
>   I am using tinymce advanced editor and wordfence plugin installed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try after deactivating all your security plugin? The possible reason is the security policy(either via some plugin or hosting) blocking access to admin-ajax.php from the front end, also check your https and http settings in general settings :)